# Stacking of magnetic moments in a polarised neutron beam

Tags: particle-physics, neutrons

Neutrons are particles that have a half spin and a magnetic moment. if you polarise a beam of neutrons so that they all align with spin +1/2 will the combined neutron beam have an overall magnetic field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.In ferromagnets the same process happens of what you just explained only with electrons.Since electrons and neutrons are fermions its the same thing.